# cannot upload image to server from android

Tags: php, android

i am developing android app that upload image from android to server. for that from my point of view android code is right but php cannot upload image to another folder in server.Here is my php code

```
<?php
  include_once  './connect_db.php';
 $db= new DBConnect();
  $response=array();
    $title=$_POST["title"];
    $description =$_POST["description"];
    $image =$_POST["image"];
    $username=$_POST["username"];
 //get image id
    $sql ="SELECT id FROM story ORDER BY id ASC";
    $sql1="SELECT id,name FROM account WHERE username='$username'";

    $res = mysqli_query($db->conn,$sql);
    $user=mysqli_query($db->conn,$sql1);
    while($rows =mysqli_fetch_array($user)){
   $user_id=$rows[0];
   $name =$rows["name"];
    }
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
$id = $row['id']+1;
 }
 if($id==null)
 {
  $id=1;
  }
 $path = "image_of_child/$id.png";

 $actualpath = "http://www.achieversnepal.com/savechild/$path";

   // mysql query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO story(name,title,description,image) VALUES('$name','$title','$description','$actualpath')";
     if(mysqli_query($db->conn,$sql)){
          file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
          if(mysqli_query($db->conn,"INSERT INTO user_story(story_id,user_id) VALUES($id,$user_id)"))
          {

          }
          $response["success"]=1;
          $response["message"]="Story uploaded successfully!!!";
          die(json_encode($response));
        }
     else{
         $response["success"]=0;
          $response["message"]="Error during upload!!";
          die(json_encode($response));
          }
```

?>

is there any problem in `file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image))`?? but same code worked when tested in wamp..:) :)